# ExtJS - Loop through CheckBoxGroup

Tags: javascript, extjs

I would like to get all of the checked items in a checkboxgroup that is part of a formpanel. Ultimately they would be saved back to database as a string, comma separated value format.

Thanks for any guidance or assistance you can provide.

Here is how I have my group defined:

```
new Ext.form.CheckboxGroup({
            id: 'newId',
            fieldLabel: 'Group A',
            name: 'broker',
            allowBlank: false,
            columns: 1,
            items: [{
                boxLabel: 'All',
                name: 'all',
                id: 'null'
            },
            {
                boxLabel: 'FS',
                name: 'fs',
                id: '1'
            },
            {
                boxLabel: 'Royal A',
                name: 'ra',
                id: '2'
            },
            {
                boxLabel: 'Point',
                name: 'sp',
                id: '6'
            }]
        })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `CheckBoxGroup`'s `getValue()` method. From the [API docs](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/):

> getValue():
>
> Gets an array of the selected
>   Ext.form.Checkbox in the group.
>
> Returns: An array of the selected checkboxes.

You can then call `join(",")` on the returned Array to get a comma-separated list.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried getChecked for getting all checked boxes.

DescCheck.getChecked();

You should use getValue(), It returns the array of selected values.

You can get that by looping through array like this

```
var selectedValue=  DescCheckGroup.getChecked();
for(var i=0;i<selectedValue.length;i++){
    console.log(select[i].inputValue);
}
```

Please see the following answers:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27414218/2935802
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18309126/2935802