# Get CheckboxGroup (or RadioGroup) values [EXTJS 3.4]

Tags: extjs, checkbox

I have a checkboxgroup and a radiogroup. For both of them, I want to catch several values. 
For the checkboxGroup

```
var DescCheck = new Ext.form.CheckboxGroup({
    fieldLabel: 'Description of service : <span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0); padding-left: 2px;">*</span>',
    width : 540,
    labelSeparator : '',
    items: [
        {boxLabel: 'Direct', name: 'Direct', inputValue: 'Direct'},
        {boxLabel: 'Fixed-day', name: 'day', inputValue: 'Fixed'},
        {boxLabel: 'Weekly', name: 'Weekly', inputValue: 'Weekly'}
    ]
});
```

I tried `DescCheck.getValue()` but it returned me

> [object Object]

I tried `DescCheck.getValue().inputValue` and it returned me nothing.

For the radioGroup

```
var TypeCheck = new Ext.form.RadioGroup({

    items: [
        {boxLabel: 'New 1', name: '1', inputValue: '1'},
        {boxLabel: 'New 2', name: '2', inputValue: '2'},
        {boxLabel: 'New 3', name: '3', inputValue: '3'}
    ]
```

I tried `TypeCheck.getValue().inputValue` but it returned only the first selected item. How can I catch several checked boxes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you tried [getChecked](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.form.CheckboxGroup-method-getChecked) for getting all checked boxes.

```
DescCheck.getChecked();
```

**Update**

You should use `getValue()`, It returns the array of selected values.

You can get that by looping through array like this

```
var selectedValue = DescCheck.getValue();

for(var i=0;i<selectedValue.length;i++){
    console.log(select[i].inputValue);
}
```

Comment: unfortunately getChecked is not available in sencha 3.4

Answer (score 0):

In my project works this below...

```
   var selectedOptions = DescCheck.getChecked(); // DescCheck.getValue();

   for (var i = 0; i < selectedOptions.length; i++) {
      console.log(  selectedOptions[i].inputValue  );
   }
```